# Extracting multiple words from a string

Tags: sql, string, extract

I need to only get the names from a String that looks something like:

`I have a cat called Bob and a rabbit called John and a dog called Betty`

Using SQL and getting each pet name into a separate column.

**Edit**

I've tried using:

```
substring(string, CHARINDEX('called', string) + 7, CHARINDEX('and', string,  CHARINDEX('called', string)) - CHARINDEX('called', string - 7) as name
```

Comment: can you please post your tried query?

Comment: I the capital letter the only hint? Just splitt this in single words and check if the first letter is capitalized...

Comment: How u will identify that the word is a pet?

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a site where you ask people to do your homework.

Comment: I'd identify the word is a pet because it comes after the word called and before the next space (it won't necessarily be capitalised)

Comment: so: splitt your string at `called ` and take the first word of the fragment.

Comment: And how is something -- other than a human at this point -- supposed to know what a pet name is in a string?  This is surely not functionality that any database provides.

Comment: this is a bit easy if you could go for Pl-Sql where in you have to identify multiple occurrences of 'and' and 'called'

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code snippet is product specific.)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: I'm using sql server

Answer (score 0):

use find and subtring_index. if the syntax of the string is always same you can use substing_index only by splitting on spaces